# Internal error, too much debug info returned to client, in Spring REST

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-rest

If there is an exception thrown within my Spring REST code, the server sends something similar to the following back to the client:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1502184648199,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.foo.DataAccessException",
  "message": "SQL [select * from my_table]: Table does not exist",
  "path": "/my-api"
}
```

I am worried that much too much internal information is exposed to the client, if it's installed this way on the live system. It might contain SQL indicating our table structure, or any other information that might be in an Exception. (Although I'll admit it's useful for debugging on the test system.)

How can I prevent this detailed information being sent to the client? (Ideally still keep it behaving this way on our test system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your ExceptionHandler to define the custom response format in case of exception. Just define ExceptionHandler and override the default response format. 
Sample code:

```
    @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "error occurred");
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}
```

take a look at [Custom Error message spring rest](http://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api)

Comment: I notice that this now not only runs any arbitrary Exception through this code, but also exceptions if the request JSON is not valid. Without this code, I get a 400 error in the case JSON is invalid (which is good). Is there any way to keep Spring's default behavior for invalid JSON (400 error) but have this new functionality to prevent Spring printing internal details in exception messages in the case of an uncaught exception?

Comment: in that case you need to define ExceptionHandler for the 400 errors with response format similler to Spring and leave the catch all Handler above as defined above.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced with the same problem recently and I suggest you to try this way:

https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/06/spicy-spring-custom-error-json-response-with-errorattributes/

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);

        if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()){

            Throwable throwable = getError(requestAttributes);
            if(throwable!=null) {
                Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
                if (cause != null) {
                    Map<String, Object> causeErrorAttributes = new HashMap<>();
                    causeErrorAttributes.put("exception", cause.getClass().getName());
                    causeErrorAttributes.put("message", cause.getMessage());
                    errorAttributes.put("cause", causeErrorAttributes);
                }
            }
        }else{
            errorAttributes.remove("message");
            errorAttributes.remove("exception");
        }
        return errorAttributes;
    }

}
```